# Basic CSS: background img not loading

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web "development", and I'm having troubles loading a full screen image as background. I've tried several way (described below), read documentation and everything looks fine to me... but it's still not working.

Here is my HTML structure (#home is contained in body):

```
<div id="home">
  <div class="landing-text">
    <h1>H1 TITLE</h1>
    <h3>H3 TITLE</h3>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Come in !</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my CSS (may not be fully finished, I'm following a tutorial):

```
#home {
    background: url("img/mountains.jpeg");
    display: table; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

I've also tried to delete everything except the 1st line to make it simpler.

Finally, my folder structure (path looks ok, the file is loaded in VSCode when I use CTRL + clic on the path):

```
- index.html
- style.css
- img
  |__ - mountains.jpeg
```

I've tried replacing " with ', background by background-image, replacing #home by .home (and changing the html file : id to class), cleanin my browser cache... but nothing worked. To me, my code looks exactly like the example in the w3school website, but I should miss something.

What am I doing wrong?

Full code:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #23415c;
  padding: 1% 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.navbar-brand {
  min-height: 55px;
  padding: 0 15px 5px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
  color: #d5d5d5;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a.active {
  color: #fff;
}

#home {
  background: url("img/mountains.jpeg");
  display: table;
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Landing Page Website Tutorial</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class ="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapse-main">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/w3newbie.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-main">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="#" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="#" href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a class="#" href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a class="#" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="home">
  <div class="landing-text">
    <h1>My buddie's name :^)</h1>
    <h3>Behind sound</h3>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Come in !</a>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="padding">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img src="img/bootstrap.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
        <h2>All about how it sounds</h2>
        <p class="lead">Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. 
          Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500</p>
        <p class="lead">Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. 
            Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="padding">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <h4>Blablabla</h4>
        <p>Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. 
           Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <img src="img/sass.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <p>Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. 
          Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <img src="img/less.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="fixed">
</div>

<div class="padding">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
              <h4>Bloblobloblo</h2>
              <p>Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. 
                Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500
                Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. 
                Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500</p>
              <p>Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. 
                  Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500
                  Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. 
                  Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <img src="img/bootstrap2.png" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Contact me</h3>
      <br>
      <h4>contact info here</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Connect</h3>
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-spotify"></a>
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-soundcloud"></a>
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-bandcamp"></a>
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="img/b.png" class="icon">    
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>


</body>
</html>
```

[image: Network tab]

As @Benjamin said, it looks like it's an OS problem.

---

## Solved

Solution: properly setting up my development environment

Comment: I think your problem is in the name of the file double check it

Comment: check the console to see if there's a 404 for the image resource, that will help you solve

Comment: Sadly it's not, that's what I first thought. Can I admit that the path is ok if the image is loaded in VSCode by pressing CTRL + clicing on the path ? 

The path (folder+files) looks ok to me since this trick works 

(I feel like i'm not clear, sorry if that's the case)

Comment: No 404 error, just an error about HTML encoding.

So my image is loading but not showing up ?

Edit : it's a pretty big image, it shouldnt be cover by my nav or anything else

Comment: if the css is linked properly do you maybe have query string params at the end of your url in the address bar? Since you are not using a relative path to include the image this might be a problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=image+not+loading

Comment: My url ends with "index.html" without any parameters, thanks for this tips tho !

Comment: It could be a cache issue too. Try to reload your page with CTRL+F5 (hard reload).

Comment: please show the output of your network tab in the browser console (open the console then reload the page)

Comment: You could try to change the image url to `"./img/mountains.jpeg"`

Comment: ok the network tab shows neither your css file nor your image being requested so the problem lais within the inclusion of your style.css file

Comment: This is confusing, I get your point (great one), but my I can see the appearance of my website changing ... So the CSS is not loading, but still affecting my page ? Oo

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe there is a problem with your server config. When I'm running your code locally the css and the image are both loaded (either when going vial localhost or by directly opening the index.html in my browser)

Comment: Well you resolved it I guess ! I should have say that I'm also new to Linux environment ! Big thanks man, I'll dive into it :). Edit : somehow I deleted my comment saying "maybe it's linked to the OS I'm using", at that time there were spaces and no priviledges for basic users on the folder. I gotta go, thanks again, you're the man :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the solution, but here is something to check.

What is the parent element to div `#home`?

If that parent element (div?) is not `position:relative` or `absolute` or `fixed`, then the `height:100%;width:100%` will be zero and the image will be there, but invisible. Percents don't work if the parent div is not one of the above.

Another thing to check is in DevTools (F12 in Chrome), hover over the css code where the image is specified and if the link is valid you will see a thumbnail image of the linked image. If you don't see that, you know that the image is not linked.

NOTE THAT if your css file is in a separate folder, your image path must be *relative* to the css file (so, if your css is in something like `css/styles.css`, then the link should be `../img/mountains.jpg`

### XAMPP / WAMP / MAMP

This might fix your OS problems.

Are you aware of the XAMPP / WAMP / MAMP / etc environments? On a Windows or Mac computer, you can install one of the above (XAMPP has versions for Windows / Mac or Linux - Wamp is Windows - Mamp is Mac) and they each install the full environment you need to create a test webserver environment on your computer. For example, they all include:

```
* Apache (the webserver)
* PHP (server-side language)
* MySQL (now called MariaDB due to copyright issues)
* perl
```

After installing the environment, open your browser and in the address bar type `localhost` and press Enter. There's the default web page, which you can change / edit / replace / etc.

Personally, I prefer [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) (used it for years), but all work fine. MAMP has been expanded and now has a Windows version also. WAMP is now called WAMPSERVER.

With XAMPP, it installs whereever you tell it (I usually accept the default of c:\xampp) and then your "website" is found in `c:\xampp\htdocs` *(for HyperText Docs, as in HTml)*. You can create a folder in there, say `bob`, and create an `index.html` in that bob folder, and then you would see that "website" by type this in the browser: `http://localhost/bob`

The `localhost` folder (i.e. really the `c:\xampp\htdocs` folder) is what, on a normal shared hosting account like you would purchase from GoDaddy, would be the `public_html` folder.

Web Hosts: avoid GoDaddy. Instead, check out NameCheap, WebHostPython and A2. You get more for less, without billing surprises. Expect to pay $50/year for the hosting, and $15/20 per year for the domain name. For example, at [webhostpython](https://www.webhostpython.com/pythonhosting.html) you get 5 domains just like at GoDaddy, but you also get the ability to use both python and node.js, which you do not get at most other hosts. Also, the best place to purchase a new domain is over at [NameCheap](https://www.namecheap.com/domains/domain-name-search.aspx#pricing) - their sales are fantastic. For example, at the time of this writing, you can purchase a `.site` or `.fun` domain for under $1 (for the first year, which is great for throw-away domains you just want for testing).

Comment: my div #home is inside <body>. I've to set position:relative, or absolute or fixed to <body> but it didnt worked
Thanks for that knowledge tho !

Comment: Eheh dw I'm not offesed by downvoters, automoderation is a great thing ! Adding this detail !

Not sure to understand which answer you want me to delete, but I'll just edit my post and add comments, instead of answers ! Thanks for teaching :)

Comment: Now I can upvote, and for sure I'll do it for usefull answers ! I so glad to quickly find answers to my questions thanks to that system that I can't imagine not doing it. Sadly, my problem isnt solved yet (I took few hours off, spent my whole day in front of my screen). @Benjamen added really usefull comments, I'm now properly setting up my web developpement environment, I hope it'll fix the problem. I should have said I'm also new to Linux environment and that I'd just created a /var/www folder to start working. See you man, thanks for your time and kindness :)

Comment: Clement, see update to my answer (above) with info re XAMPP/WAMP/MAMP - this might fix your OS problems. *Salut alors, et bonne chance* (BTW, you should upvote ALL answers that you find helpful (since it costs you nothing), and select ONE answer that is the best information to solve your question. Do not prefer the `earliest` answer, choose the `best` answer. Finally, it is possible (and often done) to both upvote *and* choose as correct. Doing that is like saying, "This is the best answer AND it was really helpful"

Comment: Thanks a lot @gibberish, that's exactly what I did today and it worked perfectly ! But I dont really understand tbh, why was some CSS loading (my navbar design for example), and some wasnt (the background:url(...); for example) ? Thanks for your recommendation about web hosting, I see that you're anticipating my next questions :p 
It feels really great to be supported that way, thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

check whether you have linked your css link to your html correctly.

Ex:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

or to be more convincing, try putting your css inside the html by using a `<style>` element in the `<head>` section.

Ex:

```
<style>
    #home {
        background: url("img/mountains.jpeg");
        display: table; 
        height: 100%; 
        position: relative; 
        width: 100%;
        background-size: cover; 
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Sorry I missread your answer ! (partialy read, that's even worst from me... mea culpa)

When I add the CSS into <head>, i've got a blank page loading (where my imae should be), eventho the path to my CSS file looks ok : <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>